# How to extract string between two regexes passed as variables to awk?

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I'm trying to extract some text in a passage that is between two strings that are being saved in variables.
What is wrong with the following way?

#### input:

```
module dft ( a, b, c, clk, z, test_si, test_se );

input [7:0] a;

dft_DW_mult_uns_1 mult_31 ( .a(a), .b(b), .product(reg0) );

endmodule
```

#### output:

```
input [7:0] a;

dft_DW_mult_uns_1 mult_31 ( .a(a), .b(b), .product(reg0) );
```

using the following code:

```
try="module dft";

awk '/$try/{flag=1; next} /endmodule/{flag=0} flag' dft_syn.v
```

but it doesn't recognize the $try variable.

Comment: BTW, the bash tag isn't really appropriate here -- this question is much more about awk, which is its own separate language. (awk is not at all part of bash -- you can, and often do, have awk installed on a system that doesn't have bash at all).

Comment: ...having "BASH:" in the title implied that you wanted a pure-bash solution (which I *could* write, but the relevant awk is far terser).

Comment: It'll work if you use double quotes, instead of single quotes (otherwise shell will not expand your 'try' variable). But it's safer to use -v awk option (like in the answer below).

Comment: ("safer", to be clear, meaning there's actual security impact to doing otherwise -- using string concatenation to generate code means that someone who controls those strings can run arbitrary code, which is as a practice the cause of the entire injection-based class of attacks).

Comment: Hi, I have trouble with all of those topics of Bash, awk, sed, etc... How would you solve it with bash? I tried to look for a solution for this with bash and couldn't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
sm="module dft"
em="endmodule"

awk -v sm="$sm" -v em="$em" '$0 ~ em{p=0} p; $0 ~ sm{p=1}' file
```

...which property emits as output:

```
input [7:0] a;

dft_DW_mult_uns_1 mult_31 ( .a(a), .b(b), .product(reg0) );
```

- Use `-v var="value"` to pass command line variables from shell to `awk`
- Set and reset variable `p` when you encounter start or end tags

Comment: Thank you very much! I really don't know how you people are so familiar with all those topics, it amazes me! Could you please explain what does the last line mean? with $0 and "~"? Thank you!

Comment: `$0 ~ em` returns true when a line matches string contained in variable `sm`. Same is the case for `$0 ~ sm`